# Multiple text into dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 50 text files all with multiple words like this

```
View(file1.txt)
one
two
three
four
cuatro

View(file2)
uno
five
seis
dos
```

Each file has only one row of words and different lengths.
I want to create a dataframe in R that has the content of each file into a column and the column name is the file name.

```
   file1    file2  ...........etc
1  one      uno
2  two      five
3  three    seis
4  four     dos
5  cuatro
```

So far I have loaded all the files into a list like this:

```
files<- lapply(list.files(pattern = "\\.txt$"),read.csv,header=F) 
> class(files)
[1] "list"
df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(files), ncol= length(files)))
```

which is definitely close but wrong because there are not holes (and some columns should have more data than others) and its also not automatically naming the columns.

Comment: do all the files have the same column names?

Comment: @Onyambu they don't have column names, see "header = F"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to get file with the max length, and use that length to complete the others (with fewer lengths) filling up with `NA` in order to make it possible to work with multiple vectors.
You can achieve that with different approaches. Here it's a way to do that.

```
files <- sapply(list.files(pattern = "\\.txt$"), readLines)
max_len <- max(sapply(files_data, length))

df <- data.frame(sapply(seq_along(files), function(i) {
  len <- length(files[[i]])
  if(len < max_len) {
    files[[i]] <- append(files[[i]], rep(NA, max_len - len))
  } else {
    files[[i]]
  }
}))

names(df) <- basename(tools::file_path_sans_ext(names(files)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, get filenames, read them in, get the maximum number of rows, then extend the number of rows. Finally, convert to data.frame:

```
f <- list.files(pattern = "\\.txt$", full.names = TRUE)
names(f) <- tools::file_path_sans_ext(basename(f))

res <- lapply(f, read.table)

maxRow <- max(sapply(res, nrow))

data.frame(lapply(res, function(i) i[seq(maxRow), ]))

#    file1 file2
# 1    one   uno
# 2    two  five
# 3  three  seis
# 4   four   dos
# 5 cuatro  <NA>
```

Comment: Great, one can further reduce this code (-1line and -code in the last line) by reading them directly using `sapply` and `readLines`, which results in a named list, creating the data.frame by using `data.frame(sapply(files, "[", 1:max_len))`.

Comment: @CainãMaxCouto-Silva Thanks, I prefer clear, step by step solutions, this is not a [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).